# How to generate unique forms with ID's?

Tags: php, database, forms

My company is in need of a form we can send to our customers with different options they can choose from. We are interested in what option they choose and want to log it in a database.

We would like generate a form so that it gets a unique ID to send to the customer
Example: http://companysite.com/form.php?id=123456789

And when the customer clicks the link it leads to a form with options customized for them.
Example:

> ```
> Regarding order 12345
> We have different options and you need to choose one:
> Option1: [ ]
> Option2: [ ]
> Option3: [ ]
> [SUBMIT]
> ```

What is the best way to achieve this? I guess I need to develop some kind of panel to generate these forms with.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a column with `INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`, possibly the `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Why don't you use one of the online services for this kind of survey. I.e. surveymonkey.com

Comment: I prefer to do it myself

Comment: It's not such a good idea to just use an auto incremented ID to show different kind of forms. Because any customer who receivs a link with an id from you just could increase or decrease his own ID by 1 and would get a form that was ment for someone else. Instead you should use some sort of random generated hash value as ID.